# what is difference between 1/3 and 1./3 in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
print (1/3)
print (1./3)
```

I don't see difference between (1/3) and (1./3). 
When should I use one or the other, and why?

Comment: please learn to copy/paste code snippets as _text_, not as images...

Comment: In Python 3.x, this will male no difference. In Python 2.x, the first form will perform an integer division and evals to `0`, which _does_ make a difference.

Comment: In addition to @brunodesthuilliers: You should also consider the different output of `/`-division and `//`-division.

Comment: hi @quốc-huy, `1/3` will return 0 as it is an integer division in `python-2`. Use `1./3` to get the results. `Python3` does not see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done to make sure the output is a floating point number. 1./3 means 1.0 / 3 which would return 0.33333...

1/3 would produce 0 as an integer

EDIT: This is only valid in Python 2

Comment: can you please add it is only for python2?

Comment: Only in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Python version you are using:

With the dot you can specify that the number should be treated as floating point number otherwise it will be an integer.

In Python 2 the devision of an integer will result in an integer value. In this case 0.3333 will be rounded to 0. Whereas in Python3 the devision will result in a floating point number never the less the dividend is an integer or a floating point number. In this case it will be in every case 0.3333